# Identify the the most web application that consume memory in iis 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

How to identify the web application on the default application pool that that use the a huge amount of memory?

**EDIT**
My application pool contains many apps, and i can't separate or stop them, can i know what resources are used for some specific application in my multi-application application pool?

Comment: Is it possible that you assign your apps to different pools and then check which instance of the `w3wp` consumes the memory?

Comment: Why do you have multiple applications in the same pool?  It's much simpler to find this out when they're split into their own pools.

Comment: I have multiple apps on default app pool, and it is very difficult to separate theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Performance monitor, open it, then click "Add Counter" then choose "Asp.Net Applications" or "ASP.Net Apps vx.xxxxx", then select your counter.

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to do this in the past as well for web servers running more than one application pool.  As per [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1211/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool/): "If you need to identify which application pool is associated with a particular w3wp.exe process, open an Administrative Command Prompt, switch into the %windir%\System32\inetsrv folder (cd %windir%\System32\inetsrv) and run appcmd list wp. This will show the process identifier (PID) of the w3wp.exe process in quotes. You can match that PID with the PID available in Task Manager."

This is exactly what I did.

Comment: The problem is there are some w3wp.exe process takes a huge amount of memory, and this process serve all web apps on my server, i can't easily separate theme, there are more than 15 sites in the same pool, but this huge memory consumption is new, i didn't add any apps recently.

Comment: In that case, I'd agree with the commentators above.  You could separate the applications into their own app pools, noting the addition overhead for each process that goes along with that.  Then use my recommendation above to decide which process belongs to which application.  IME, it's been worthwhile to configure a memory consumption limit in each application pool to have the pool automatically recycle itself after hitting that maximum.  Perhaps this isn't a sustainable remedy if this is a constant issue, but see more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725749(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: In this case there are no answer to my main question? i can't know the which specific application uses the memory in my multi-application application pool?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  You're hosting several web apps within one process.  It's not the processes job to know about the app pool (specifically) and/or knowing what the memory consumption of each web app is.  What information may be available to distinguish these, is going to be in APPCMD.  When I've troubleshot memory issues similar to these, it's been fairly fruitless unless the problem is common or obvious.  In any case, if you have access to that machine, it would only take minutes to separate them.  Otherwise, set your app pool to recycle which is common in practice. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: I got it, you can do it using "Performance Monitor" it is a verrrrrry good built-in application from windows.

Comment: Ah, well done.  I'm familiar with the tool, but unfamiliar with how it will break down those details.  I'll definitely look into this if I find myself in the same situation.  Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that in IIS, if you have multiple web apps sharing 1 app pool, the w3wp.exe process will isolate each web site into its own AppDomain.  If you are using .NET 4, it looks like there is some [performance metrics that can be read per AppDomain.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hasansheik/diagnostic-and-performance-monitoring-in-dotnet-4-0/)

This means that you might be able to add some code in your applications that dump out the stats of their own AppDomain, which you can then aggregate and report on.

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems like it might help...

---

A really simple form of doing this may be to just in your `Application_Start()` method, set `AppDomain.MonitoringIsEnabled = true;`

Then have a "stats.aspx" page that dumps `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalProcessorTime` and whatever other stats, to a label.